# Sql - Update sql with subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I trying to update mysql data table with subquery . Can i anyone can please guide me . These the code i trying.

```
UPDATE table_name SET meta_value = 'day' 
WHERE post_id IN (
    SELECT post_id FROM table_name 
    WHERE meta_key = '_min_date' AND meta_value='0') 
AND meta_key = '_min_date_unit'
```

Comment: So what happens when you run it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `join` instead:

```
Update table_name t join
       table_name tt
       on tt.post_id = t.post_id and tt.meta_key = '_min_date' and
          tt.meta_value = '0'
    set t.meta_value = 'day' 
where t.meta_key = '_min_date_unit';
```

MySQL has a limitation where the table being updated should only be referenced in the `update` clause using a `join`.  Your version of the query would work in just about any other database.